# How inflate expandableListView?

Tags: android

If I can inflate a ListView this way, how I can inflate a ExpandableListView?

This is part of code for inflate ListView in navigation drawer, but I need with expandableListView.

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {



/*(CODE...)*/


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {        


    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
            }));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;


}


/*(CODE...)*/
```

Comment: That depends...are you using an `ExpandableListView`? As far as inflating, it works as it does with any other `View`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the ListView in the layout XML with an ExpandableListView and cast is as one in code:

```
mDrawerListView = (ExpandableListView) ...
```

Comment: I've done that and I got error of "Error inflating class fragment"

Comment: Then post a stack trace from logcat.